# Accidentally overwrote iPhone device location via Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

So I'm working on a location-based iPhone app. I'm mainly testing on the iOS simulator, and as such using the Core Location Simulation. All good - I can pretend to be in New York or San Francisco or wherever.

Then I move to testing my app on my iPhone, with that checkbox still enabled. I go for a walk (in, like, the actual real world), pull out Google Maps, and realise that **my actual, not-simulator iPhone is using a simulated location**. In this instance my iPhone is stuck thinking that it's in London (where I live), but right central in Picadilly Circus, not where I am.

I get home, open up Xcode, and to make sure I've nailed down the cause (rather than just a weird GPS bug etc), change the 'default location' to Johannesburg. Unplug my phone, open Google Maps (and Foursquare, to be sure), same deal. Stuck in Johannesburg.

**So it's definitely this panel here that's borked my phone**, but I can't figure out how to reset it.

Things I've tried that don't seem to work:

- changing 'default location' to 'none' & rerunning
- disabling 'allow location simulation' & rerunning

So it seems once you've given your iPhone an arbitrary location to pretend to be in, just disabling that doesn't fix it.

[image: Location Simulation]

Any ideas? I'm going travelling in a few days and really need my GPS to work!

Comment: just `Reset Location & Privacy` . turnoff location service .
restart your phone  .. turn on location service . try using google maps .. it work for me ..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This has happened to me before, it was very strange and mysterious!

I don't remember how I fixed it, but: have you tried `Reset Location & Privacy` in the Settings app? If all else fails, I suspect `Reset All Settings` would maybe work.

As I try to remember, I think maybe hard rebooting the phone might also work (just turn it off, turn it back on).

Comment: Remember that you currently (iOS 8.0.2) [may lose all you documents in the cloud](http://www.macrumors.com/2014/09/29/reset-all-settings-icloud-drive-bug/) when you reset ...

Comment: This has happened to me and my solution was turn off the phone and turn it back. iOS 8.3

Answer (score 17):

While you have your device connected to the debugger there is a little button at the top of the debug panel. Right here:

[image]

Click on that and you can select 'don't simulate location', exit the app, and I think you'll be good to go.

I'm a little foggy too on how that relates to the location defined in the scheme and the location set in the simulator. I usually find it easier to set a location in the simulator itself rather than in the scheme (at least when testing in the simulator is possible) to avoid issues like this. In the simulator if you enter a location under 'Debug > Location > Custom Location...' while the simulator is on the springboard the location will persist between launches of the app and the simulator.

Comment: This is mental... I've been experiencing this for years now and never thought this could be the cause of it! 

While rebooting does work, this should be selected as the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! I went to pick up my son earlier, who'd fallen off his bike and cut his knee while out riding some trails with his bigger brother. We found each other, but not thanks to using my iPhone's GPS, which thought it was about 1000km away in Berlin! Hopefully future rescue missions will be easier!

Answer (score 2):

just `Reset Location & Privacy` . turnoff `location service` . restart your phone .. turn on `location service` . try using google maps .. it work for me ..

Comment: "Just" a restart is enough for me.

Answer (score 2):

The important step is the hard reset after resetting location settings. Not sure if you need to do anything in Xcode, but it is a good idea to select 'Don't simulate location'

Answer (score 1):

Go back to Xcode (or whatever coding software you are using) and rerun the application, then select don't simulate location.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Edit Scheme...**, then select **Run** in left panel. In options, set **Default Location** under **Core Location** to None.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Goto Settings>Privacy>Location Services. Turn-Off Location Services. Restart the phone. Open Google maps. A popup will come to enable location service, click on the options given that will take you directly to Settings. If popup didn't appear in Google Maps, click on Mylocation button at the bottom. Enable Location services and get back to Google Maps. It re-enabled the real Location for me.

Answer (score 0):

[As suggested in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26261248/accidentally-overwrote-iphone-device-location-via-xcode?rq=1#comment59446596_26261574) if you don't have Xcode handy, you can just **power cycle the iPhone** and this seems to be sufficient. You don't need to reset any settings. This worked this morning for my iPhone anyway, recalling it from a winter sojourn of Berlin.